# Getting null pointer when Joblauncher.run is called in spring batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a batch job. I trigger by :
joblauncher.run(job, jobparameter)
Joblauncher.run(job,jobparameters) returns null pointer.
Joblauncher is autowired

[error stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkm6E.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question to give more context

Answer (score 0):

Can you please attach your stacktrace here. And share how are you creating the jobLauncher, job and jobParameters. I wanted to comment, but I can't.

Comment: The attached screenshot is not enough to understand the problem. Please provide a [minimalistic example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can help us to reproduce and get better insight of the issue.